# Generate scale-free and small-world networks

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm googling around a lot in order to find a very basic version of algorithms able to generate scale-free and small-world networks. Unfortunately, my search is not giving results.

I don't need something very complicated. Just need something that explain how to generate the desired networks and why the algorithms work that way.

I know very well how to generate Erdos-Renyi graph, but I can't find something similar for scale-free and small-world cases.

Pseudo-code, as well as C/C++, Maltab, Java and Python are good for me.

Comment: +1 for some definitions I wasn't aware existed. Why not generate the nodes first and then generate edges with some probability? that takes care of scale-free. Then, by some (random?) threshold, add edges to make nodes "closer" if they are too far apart. That should solve small world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about scale-free or small-world networks (only have heard the names), but a quick google search led me to the following wikipedia pages:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model

> The Barabási–Albert (BA) model is an algorithm for generating random scale-free networks using a preferential attachment mechanism

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model

> The Watts–Strogatz model is a random graph generation model that
>   produces graphs with small-world properties, including short average
>   path lengths and high clustering

Both algorithms are well-descriped in these Wikipedia pages.

Comment: thanks very much. Anyway, the description of algorithm lack of some information. For example the algo for BA begins with "The network begins with an initial connected network of $m_0$ nodes." What means connected network? Any network? A fully connected network? A network with only one connected component?

Comment: It does not really matter. You generally take a smal clique. But in the end, after a large number of iterations, this does not significantly affect the final network. The only constraint is that each node should have at least one neighbor, otherwise it'll never be picked to attach new nodes, and it will stay isolated. BTW, if you find the Wikipedia articles incomplete, just consulte the original papers they cite.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is not what you want, but in Netlogo there is a really good example in the models library for both type of networks.

The code to generate a small world network in netlogo v. 5 is:

```
to setup_network
  if network = "small-world" [
    let max-who 1 + max [who] of turtles
    let sorted sort ([who] of turtles)
    foreach sorted[ ?1 ->
      ask turtle ?1 [
        let i 1
        repeat number-of-links [
          create-link-with turtle ((?1 + i) mod max-who)
          set i i + 1
        ]
      ]
    ]
    repeat round (rewire-prop * number-of-agents) [
      ask one-of turtles [
        ask one-of my-links [die]
        create-link-with one-of other turtles with [link-with myself = nobody]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  if display-network? [
    layout-circle (sort turtles) (max-pxcor - 1)
    display
  ]
end
```

Im sure the models library can help you out further.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check this.